# what backup/sync app is recommended for android phones (without computer)?

Tags: sync, applications, backup

good software to automatically sync and backup your files without having to connect it to a computer via USB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I heard [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/android) is a good alternative, but I have not tried it myself.

Comment: the app is called dropbox? is it available in android market?

Comment: I've have DropBox installed, I don't think or can find a way to get it to sync automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you have root, I really recommend you TitaniumBackup!